# Button action to iterate through items in an array

Tags: arrays, function, swiftui

I'm trying to create a button action that upon pressing the button it will display the next item in the array.

Here's the data model:

```
struct Option: Identifiable {
let id = UUID()
let itemLabel: String
let choice1: String
let choice2: String
let choice3: String
let choice4: String
let correctItem: String

}

extension Option {
static func all() -> [Option] {
    return [
        Option(itemLabel: "Vulputate Justo Aenean Mattis Porta", choice1: "A", choice2: "B", choice3: "C", choice4: "D", correctItem: "D"),
        Option(itemLabel: "Vulputate Justo Aenean Mattis Porta", choice1: "A", choice2: "B", choice3: "C", choice4: "D", correctItem: "D")
]
}
}
```

So I'm trying to figure out how to create function that steps thru the items in the array. Upon pressing the button I want to be able to display the following 'itemLabel' text in a text element, replacing the previous one.

```
 Text(Option.all()[0].itemLabel)
```

Above is how I'm currently displaying the itemLabel

Comment: I'm only guessing here, because you haven't given enough code (along with desired results) to duplicate things. First? This doesn't sound to me like a SwiftUI issue - rather, you tagged it that because you are coding in that DSL. In other words, if this were a UIKit or AppKit app, could you make it work? I'm just trying to strip out the "noise" in your question. Second, your `all` function seems to return a two element array of... identical elements? Please, help us to help you - the code you provided isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var idx = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(Option.all()[idx].itemLabel)

            Button("Toggle direction") {
                self.idx = (self.idx + 1 < Option.all().count) ? self.idx + 1 : 0
            }
        }
    }
}


struct Option: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let itemLabel: String
    let choice1: String
    let choice2: String
    let choice3: String
    let choice4: String
    let correctItem: String

}

extension Option {
    static func all() -> [Option] {
        return [
            Option(itemLabel: "Text A", choice1: "A", choice2: "B", choice3: "C", choice4: "D", correctItem: "D"),
            Option(itemLabel: "Text B", choice1: "A", choice2: "B", choice3: "C", choice4: "D", correctItem: "D"),
            Option(itemLabel: "Text C", choice1: "A", choice2: "B", choice3: "C", choice4: "D", correctItem: "D")
        ]
    }
}
```